# state variable is null after setting state

Tags: reactjs

I'm playing with reactJS props and state and am having problems using a state variable when executing a function. When I print that variable it shows as null. However, when I set the state variable in a different function and send to console, I see that the variable is already set.

Specifically:

**app.js**

```
  const [clickedElement, setClickedElement] = useState(null);

  const onElementClick = (event, element) => { 
    console.log('My clicked element is', element);
    setClickedElement(element);
  };

  const removeCustomElement = (e) => {
    console.log("In here");
    console.log("Removed clicked element is:" + JSON.stringify(clickedElement));
  }
```

I then have another file which I import. That file has a form in it which has a button. The function is removeCustomElement is passed through the `data` prop to that form.js file.

**form.js**

```
 <CloseButton style ={{paddingTop: '6px', marginLeft:"auto"}} onClick={data.removeCustomElement}/>
```

When I click the the close button, the `removeCustomElement` fires off correctly but I get the below. Note that the first line is from `onElementClick` and the second line is from `removeCustomElement`.

```
My clicked element is {id: '4', type: 'customNode1', position: {…}, data: {…}}
app.js:53 In here
app.js:54 Removed clicked element is:null
```

I tried wrapping it in a `useCallback()` but had no success there either. Thanks!

Edit1:
**form.js**

```
const form = ( props) => {
  const {id, data} = props;
  ...

        <div className='form1_container'>
        
        <div style = {{display:"flex"}}>
         
          <button className = "btn btn-small" onClick={handleShow}>
            <i className="icon bi-save2"></i>
          </button>
          <div  style={{ paddingTop: '2px',  boxSizing: 'content-box'}} >{data.label} </div>
          <CloseButton style ={{paddingTop: '6px', marginLeft:"auto"}} onClick={data.removeCustomElement}/>
        </div>
```

Comment: What are you using a `class base component` or a `function based component` ?

Comment: In app.js? ```const app = () => {  ...``` ? Or are you talking about the form.js?

Comment: I'm talking about form.js where you've to use the props. can you post your form.js code ?

Comment: It's a bit long, but  I posted I think what you need? Let me know if more needed, still new to reactjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't pass the second argument to element which has `onElementClick` event.

OR

If you want to save element like state, better use `useRef()`.

`const elemRef = useRef(null);`

.
.
.

`<h2 ref={elemRef} onClick={(e) => onElementClick(e, elemRef.current)} >will be clicked!</h2>`

Comment: The first argument is actually passed in by default (I think). Regardless, `onElementClick` works correctly. The `console.log` prints the correct element and then I set it.

Comment: did you fired event `onElementClick` before click `removeCustomElement` ?

Comment: That's how it appears in the console.... onElementClick is whenever something is clicked. However onElementClick is defined by the package so it may be asynchronous?

Comment: Doing the below (which presumably should fix if asynchronous?) doesn't work either: ' const  onElementClick = async (event, element) => { 
    console.log('Setting clicked element to: ', element);
    await setClickedElement(element);
  };'

Comment: can you post the code with element which has event `onElementClick`?

Comment: onElementClick is a function that is used by the 'reactFlowPackage': https://reactflow.dev/examples/custom-node/

Comment: `onElementClick` is not a function that you make? but you declare the function inside App.js.

Comment: I make onElementClick. You asked me to post the code which uses it. It's used when I set up the reactFlow block as in that link.

Comment: then when you click `removeCustomElement`, in some code your 'clickedElement` state is initiated to `null`. if you post another question that shows your all code I can  take a look.

Comment: Pretty sure this has something to do with the async nature of react. I have no other code that has the string clickedElement.

Comment: If ' const onElementClick = async (event, element) => { console.log('Setting clicked element to: ', element); await setClickedElement(element); };'  is all the `onElementClick` function doing, you don't have to use `async` keyword.